# Checking whether binary files are the same?

Tags: diff

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Binary Diff Tools On Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/106554/binary-diff-tools-on-windows)

What would be the easiest way of veryfying whether two binary files are the same, without actually opening them, checking versions and such in different programs ... ?

I primary mean files like 3d models, acad drawings, and the like, of which I have different versions, saved in different directories, and upon completing, I just want to find which are the newest, and which are different from the newest, and delete every other.

So far I've thought od md5 ? (which is slow, .... I want something that lets me click on two files, and it says - "they're not the same. move along." Any other ideas ?

*This doesn't actually fit under "diff" tag so feel free to change it, if you can think of a better alternative.*

Comment: Why not diff them, though? I use Beyond Compare or the Total Commander built-in diff tool. They simply tell me if the files are the same or not, without any extra fuss.

Comment: @alex - Because some of them are somewhat larger than usual ... in range 50-1000 mb (give or take), and that tends to crash pretty much every diff I've tried so far. I could of course check them manually, but the problem is I've got tens of them, and it is an exmtremelly tiresome process.

Comment: What platform? Linux?

Comment: Windows (CAD is not so much into linux as a platform).

Comment: How do you define newest? Is it file modification date or does it depend on some content of the files?

Comment: Yes, it is file modification date, but all I really want is just a quick way of checking whether they're the same, or not.

Comment: There are programs to check for duplicates (I have now evaluated Comparator Fast, Easy Duplicate Finder and CloneSpy.) and that compare files byte-by-byte without trying to find differences or compute MD5. But most of them are oriented towards eliminating duplicates. Worse they will not show the files that are NOT duplicates (that you want to delete).

Comment: Related question? http://superuser.com/questions/106554/binary-diff-tools-on-windows

Answer (score 3):

Use the `cmp` utility.  It's in Cygwin, for Windows users.

Answer (score 2):

```
C:\> fc/b file1 file2
```

More information about the FC (file compare) command can be found [here](http://www.computerhope.com/fchlp.htm).

---

If you have *many* files, some sort of a hash function will be the easiest way. On my (quite old) computer, `md5sum` can hash a 1 GB file in 50 seconds, and that's only because of the slow HD.

Answer (score 1):

> So far I've thought od md5 ? (which is
>   slow, .... I want something that lets
>   me click on two files, and it says -
>   "they're not the same. move along."
>   Any other ideas ?

By definition, if you want to compare two 1G files, you're going to have to read both files. There's no magic bullet that will get past that. What if the two files differ by one byte, 99.9% of the way through the file?

In terms of clicking on the files in the shell, and comparing, Beyond Compare was already mentioned, and Total Commander rocks. But if you want a simple free integrated shell utility, try Hashtab: http://hashtab.software.informer.com

You can click on a file, get the hash, select the next file, and compare with the hash you just got.

Answer (score 0):

[Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) in binary mode.

Or else [HashTab](http://beeblebrox.org/).